# Flask Malformed packet with Mysql 5.7 SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an api that was made over python 3.5 with SQLAlchemy==1.2.10
My api connects to a RDS Aurora with mysql engine 5.7.

In the api i have a get method that when executed return some lines from my database. When i run the api local pointing out
to rds every think works fine, but when the i try to execute the same get method deployed into Amazon Ecs, i get the follow error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2027, 'Malformed packet') [SQL: 'SELECT compra.compra_id AS compra_compra_id, compra.cnpj_cliente AS compra_cnpj_cliente, compra.nome_cliente AS compra_nome_cliente, compra.cnpj_agencia AS compra_cnpj_agencia, compra.nome_agencia AS compra_nome_agencia, compra.contato_atendimento AS compra_contato_atendimento, compra.assistente AS compra_assistente, compra.player AS compra_player, compra.cliente_direto AS compra_cliente_direto, compra.status AS compra_status, compra.tipo AS compra_tipo, compra.dt_criacao AS compra_dt_criacao, compra.dt_atualizacao AS compra_dt_atualizacao \nFROM compra \n LIMIT %s, %s'] [parameters: (0, 50)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Link to the api: https://globoexpress.cluster.stg.negocios.tvglobo.com.br/compras/api/v1/Order/

I just have one difference between the environments, local o call the get over http and on ecs i call over https.

I have attached my requirements.txt

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your `Mysqlclient`
`pip install --upgrade mysqlclient`

I had have the same question , but solved it  this  way